# SQL Server Merge Replication fails with "Initializing SQL Server Reconciler has failed. Try again."

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-ce, merge-replication

I'm trying to set up replication between a SQL Server 2008 R2 database and SQL Server CE 3.5. I have set up IIS 7 accordingly and get a nice "Microsoft SQL Server Compact Server Agent" when checking the publication URL (http://winserver2008/SQLReplication/sqlcesa35.dll).

However when I try http://winserver2008/SQLReplication/sqlcesa35.dll?diag I get the following:

[image]

When I try to connect to the publisher via a C# app I'm writing I get "Initializing SQL Server Reconciler has failed. Try again". i assume that means I need that 9.0 database reconciler? If so how do I install it?

On a side note this only happens when I try to connect via Integrated Windows Authentication. If I try via SQL Server authentication instead I just get an error about SQL Server missing or having an incorrect login/password.

Comment: Check profiler on the database to see if you hit it, you do not need the 9.0 reconsiler it is for SQL Server 2005

Comment: @ErikEJ - Thanks, that pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figured it out. After locating the actual error message in SQL Server Profiler it became obvious there was an issue with the access privileges of the publication. As it turns out I had to add the database user to the PAL instead of the corresponding windows account.

Answer (score 0):

The IIS web site and web application utilized by SQL CE 3.5 has to be set to allow "directory browsing". Once I turned that on, the ReadWriteDeleteMessageFile status went to SUCCESS.